# Pedir valor y sacar su cuadrado. Se repite hasta que el valor introducido sea 99

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

necesito dar un valor y poder sacar el cuadrado, y esta acción se debe de repetir hasta que el número sea 99, sé que se hará con un bucle, pero no encuentro la forma para que lo repita de la forma en la que quiero, ya que de las formas que he intentado me saca el cuadrado del número que he introducido hasta al 99 de golpe, y yo quiero que lo haga de uno en uno, hasta que sea un número mayor de 99, que en ese caso dará un error.

Os dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora, espero que me podáis ayudar:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Escribe un valor para sacar su cuadrado de 1 a 99"
read A
if [ $A -le 99 ]
   then
      cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`
      echo "El cuadrado de $A es $cuadrado"
   else
        echo "Error, el número es mayor que 99"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Efectivamente lo que necesitas es un ***bucle***, en este caso me parece más conveniente usar el `while`, aunque se puede utilizar un `for` también, pues se sabe que no debe ser superior a 99.

Entonces coloqué el `while` antes de condicional `if/else`, de la siguiente manera:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Escribe un valor para sacar su cuadrado de 1 a 99"
read A
        while [  $A -lt 100 ]; do
            # echo El contador es $A
            if [ $A -le 99 ]
            then
                cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`
                echo "El cuadrado de $A es $cuadrado"
            else
                    echo "Error, el número es mayor que 99"
            fi
            let A=A+1 
        done
```

---

## CÓDIGO OPTIMIZADO

Estuve analizando éste código, y la manera en la que se desarrolla y veo que no es eficiente pues si pones un número mayor a 99 no hace nada porque no entra en el `while`, además me di cuenta de que el condicional en `if/else` en este caso no está haciendo nada, he optimizado el código ejecutando primero el `if/else` y luego el `while`, de ésta manera funciona bien, es interesante, pues no cambie código, simplemente lo ordené para que fuese óptimo.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Escribe un valor para sacar su cuadrado de 1 a 99"
read A
    if [ $A -le 99 ]
    then
        while [  $A -lt 99 ]; do
            # echo El contador es $A
            cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`
            echo "El cuadrado de $A es $cuadrado"
            let A=A+1
        done
    else
        echo "Error, el número es mayor que 99"
    fi
```

¡Espero sea de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas de ningún bucle para hacer lo que pides (o lo que tengo entendido que pides). No es recomendable hacer bucles con `bash` aunque pueda parecer muy seductor. Para eso puedes usar otros programas. Ni siquiera necesitas de un `else`.

Lo que sugiero es usar `seq` para generar números desde el ingresado hasta el límite (que será 99) y luego utilizar `xargs` para sacar el resultado de seq y obtener los cuadrados con `bc`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare limite=99

read -p 'Escribe un valor: ' valor

[[ "$valor" -gt "$limite" ]] \
    && echo "Error, el numero es mayor a $limite" \
    && exit 1

seq "$valor" "$limite" | xargs -n1 -I {} echo {}^2 | bc
```

Cuya ejecución sería así.

```
 % ./cuadrado.sh
Escribe un valor: 999
Error, el numero es mayor a 99
 % ./cuadrado.sh
Escribe un valor: 99
9801
 % ./cuadrado.sh
Escribe un valor: 97
9409
9604
9801
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa sin depender de comando externo podría ser:

```
  echo "Escribe un valor para sacar su cuadrado de 1 a 99"
  read A
  if  [ $A  -gt 99 ]
  then
      echo Numero debe ser menor a 100
      exit
  fi
  for((i=$A;i<=99;i++));  do echo el cuadrado de $i es $(expr $i \* $i) ; done
```